# Graded-commutativity of cup product: Non-commuative coefficient ring

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

For $R$ a *commutative* ring and $X$ a topological space the cup product on the singular cohomology $H^{\ast}(X)$ is graded commutative. I have a question about the proof of this claim.

Some definitions first:

- Given topological spaces $X,Y$ and open subsets $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$, pick a chain homotopy equivalence $$EZ\colon S_{\ast}(X\times Y,X\times B \cup A \times Y;R)\rightarrow S_{\ast}(X,A;R)\otimes S_{\ast}(Y,B;R).$$ For $\alpha \in S^p(X,A;R)$ and $\beta \in S^q(Y,B;R)$, define the *cohomology cross product* as $$\alpha \times \beta:=\mu\circ(\alpha\otimes \beta)\circ EZ_{p+q}.$$

The proof I know goes as follows:

> We first show that the cohomology cross product is graded commutative. The claim then follows from $\alpha\cup \beta=\Delta^{\ast}(\alpha \times \beta)$, where $\Delta\colon X\rightarrow X\times X$ is the diagonal map and $\alpha \in H^p(X)$, $\beta \in H^q(X)$. Denote by $T\colon X\times Y \rightarrow Y\times X$ the map that swaps the arguments and by $\tau \colon S_{\ast}(Y)\otimes S_{\ast}(X) \rightarrow S_{\ast}(X)\otimes S_{\ast}(Y)$ the usual braiding in the monoidal category of chain complexes (i.e. $x\otimes y \mapsto (-1)^{\vert x \vert \vert y \vert}y\otimes x$). The chain map $\tau \circ EZ \circ T$ agrees with $EZ$ on $S_0$. Therefore it is chain homotopic to $EZ$ and we could have used $\tau \circ EZ \circ T$ to define the cross product. If we use $\tau \circ EZ \circ T$ to define the cohomological cross product (denote this operation by $\times^{\tau}$), we find $\alpha \times^{\tau} \beta= (-1)^{\vert \alpha \vert \vert \beta \vert}\beta\times \alpha.$ The claim follows.

- *Where did we use that $R$ is commutative?*
- *Why does the fact that the chain map $\tau \circ EZ \circ T$ agrees with $EZ$ on $S_0$ imply that it is chain homotopic to $EZ$? I know that if the domain of $EZ$ is a projective resolution, this is just the fundamental lemma of homological algebra. But in this case the domain of $EZ$ is generally not an exact sequence.*

Comment: I believe you mean: $\alpha \times \beta = EZ^*(\mu(\alpha \otimes \beta))$? Here $\mu$ should identify the tensor product of the cohomologies with the cohomology of the tensor product of the complexes.. I believe there you secretly use an isomorphism $R\otimes_R R \to R$. Try to define the ring structure on $R\otimes_R R$ and I think you will see all the 'problems'.

Comment: @Jonas I mean $\alpha \times \beta:=\mu\circ(\alpha\otimes \beta)\circ EZ_{p+q}$. This is well-typed. Here $\mu: R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R\rightarrow R$ denotes the ring multiplication of $R$. I don't understand the rest of your comment, starting from 'I believe there…'. Why would I consider the tensor product over $R$? My question is where *in this proof* did we use that $R$ is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first answer your second point: The Eilenberg-Zilber theorem (using the method of acyclic models) states that a natural transformation $\phi: S_*(-)\otimes S_*(-) \to S_*(-\times -) $ is uniquely determined (in the homotopy category) by what it does in degree 0. As you suspected the proof uses the fundamental lemma of homological algebra but to even get there you need acyclic models.

This remains true when working with coefficients $\phi_G : S_*(-;G)\otimes S_*(-;G) \to S_*(-\times -;G)$ (where $G$ is an abelian group, e.g. when $G = (R,+)$ is the additive group associated to a ring $R$.)

For the existence part of the Theorem you will need a ring structure.

Now your proof works if you check that the constructed map $\tau \circ EZ \circ T$ agrees with $EZ$ in degree 0.

For $X=Y=pt$ we identify $S_0(pt,R)=R$. The map $T$ is going to be the identity and $\tau:R\otimes R \to R\otimes R$ is $r \otimes s \mapsto s\otimes r$. The EZ map $\phi_R$ is going to be the ring multiplication. So in total we have to check
$$ r\cdot s \overset{?}{=} s \cdot r.$$
**EDIT:** (after reading comments) The above just 'checks' the required identity for $X=Y=pt$, I'm not saying this is a proof for anything. It is just to highlight that commutativity of $R$ should be necessary for the 'usual' graded commutativity of the cohomology.

Remark: If your ring is graded commutative and $\tau$ is the braiding in the monoidal category of chain complexes over $R$ the corresponding cross-product is still graded commutative... maybe even more general for 'braided rings' (don't know if the concept exists)

Comment: Thanks! (After having read up on the method of acyclic models), I understood everything up to 'For $X=Y=pt$ …'. Why does it suffice to check the equality only for $X=Y=pt$? In my notes it says that the EZ map from above maps $(x,y)\in S_0(X\times Y)$ to $x\otimes y \in S_0(X)\otimes S_0(Y)$, in fact it is the unique (up to chain homotopy) binatural map with this property. But now that I think about it, this was proved only for coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. The map isn't even well-typed for other coefficents. So for coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ …

Comment: … the map EZ is the map $(x,y)\mapsto x\otimes y$ in degree zero, and trivially $\tau\circ EZ \circ T$ and $EZ$ agree. So the proof in my lecture notes only works for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and where we used commutativity of $\mathbb{Z}$ was left implicit. Does that sound about right (modulo the part about my notes, which you cannot know of course)? For coefficients in (the additive group of) a ring, one has to generalize the proof of the (unique up to homotopy) existence of an $EZ$ map that has nice behaviour in degree $0$. How would this generalization look like?

Comment: More precisely, it was a proposition in my notes that there is a  chain map $S_{\ast}(-\times -;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow S_{\ast}(-;\mathbb{Z})\otimes S_{\ast}(-;\mathbb{Z})$ which maps $(x,y)$ to $x\otimes y$ in degree zero, and that this property characterises the chain map uniquely up to homotopy. What would be the analogous characterising property for coefficients in an arbitrary ring $R$?

Comment: I did not mean to claim that but in fact it is enough to check the identity for a point. This is because you are comparing to (specific) natural transformation. In fact the Yoneda Lemma can be used here in the same way it is used in the method of acyclic models.

Yes, the proof in your from your notes seems only to deal with $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: First stick to abelian groups: $G,H$. Then a generalization would be transformations $S_*(-; G)\otimes S_*(-;H) \to S_*(-\times -; G\otimes H)   $ with the obvious map in degree $0$. Now for a ring $R$ you use to the multiplication $R\otimes R \to R$ to get to $S_*(-; R)\otimes S_*(-;R) \to S_*(-\times -; R)   $. I believe this direction is more natural, while you are describing the inverse.